# Create Local Connections - SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As per the SQL Developer User's [Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RPTUG/toc.htm)

> To create (automatically generate) a database connection for each
>   unlocked user account in the Oracle database instance on the local
>   system, right-click the Connections node and select Create Local
>   Connections. The connections are placed in a folder named
>   Auto-Generated Local Connections.

In my database, I have below unlocked users

[image]

but when I right click the connections node, create local connections is disabled.

[image]

How I can enable it?

edit:

Show jdbc output is:

```
-- Database Info --
Database Product Name: Oracle
Database Product Version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Database Major Version: 12
Database Minor Version: 1
-- Driver Info --
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 12.2.0.1.0
Driver Major Version: 12
Driver Minor Version: 2
Driver URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
Driver Location: Unable to parse URL: bundleresource://48.fwk251900797/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
```

Comment: Is your DB local to where sqldev is running ?

Comment: yes. both DB and SQLdev is installed in the same laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the code behind that is doing.

1) Checking the OCI Driver is available from the ORACLE_HOME. This has to be equal to the driver sqldev is using. To test that issue this in the worksheet. This controls the enabling of the menu.

```
SQL> show jdbc
-- Database Info --
Database Product Name: Oracle
Database Product Version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Database Major Version: 12
Database Minor Version: 1
-- Driver Info --
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 12.2.0.1.0    <<<<<<<<<<< THIS VERSION <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Driver Major Version: 12
Driver Minor Version: 2
```

2) Next the code connects basically as "/ as sysdba". That means the ORACLE_SID will have to be setup in the env.

3) When all that works, we issue this sql and create a connection for each returned.

```
select username from dba_users 
                        where account_status = 'OPEN' 
                        and username not in ('SYS','MGMT_VIEW','DBSNMP','SYSMAN')
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, My database is 11g but driver version is 12.2.0.1.0